# Как совместить mysql и mysqli?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Ребята подскажите  возможно ли совместить mysql и mysqli ?

Дело в том что главный сайт работает на mysql а вот мобильную версию обновили на  mysqli она в отдел ной папки (m) можно ли сделать так что бы сайт работал на mysql а мобильная версия на  mysqli ?

Comment: Да, конечно, можно.

Comment: а как это сделать ? я загрузила новую мобильную версию но не чего не работает